# Revert commits and commit them to a branch?

Tags: git

I'm cloning a popular open source project into GitHub, and I only realized this after it was too late. I'm also trying to convert this project over to use Maven instead of Ant/Ivy for a build tool. I was able to convert the repository from SVN to Git via the aptly-named `svn2git`, then started making changes toward the Maven migration.

I failed to realize at the get-go that I needed to create a separate branch for my Maven migrations. Is there a way for me to take my revisions, remove them from `master`, and send them to a new branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds really simple to fix assuming you made all your commits to `master`.  Here's a high-level description of the steps (tailor commands to your specific repo).

- Make a new branch at your current HEAD (e.g. with `git branch <newbranch>`)
- Switch to the current `master` (`git checkout master`).
- Track down your original `master` HEAD commit and move there (e.g. `git reset --hard HEAD~n`).
- When pushing to a remote repository, use `--force` to foist the undoings onto  the repository (for example: `git push --force --all`)

Comment: @TKKocheran: Thanks for the edit and catching the `--force` bit.